# SQL query to Group By and Concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as so:

| Date | Opponent | Score | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/14/56 | Shawen | 0-18 | L |
| 09/21/56 | Dixie | 12-16 | L |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 10/29/60 | Carlisle | 0-6 | L |
| 11/12/60 | Shawen | 22-0 | W |

I'm trying to create a query which will produce this result:

| Year | W-L |
| --- | --- |
| 1956 | 1-4 |
| 1957 | 4-3 |
| 1958 | 3-6 |
| 1959 | 3-5 |
| 1960 | 7-1 |

I am able to run these queries independently:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date), COUNT(Result) From GameSummaries WHERE Result = 'W' GROUP BY YEAR(Date)
SELECT YEAR(Date), COUNT(Result) From GameSummaries WHERE Result = 'L' GROUP BY YEAR(Date)
```

Which return:

| Year | W |
| --- | --- |
| 1956 | 1 |
| 1957 | 4 |
| 1958 | 3 |
| 1959 | 3 |
| 1960 | 7 |

And:

| Year | L |
| --- | --- |
| 1956 | 4 |
| 1957 | 3 |
| 1958 | 6 |
| 1959 | 5 |
| 1960 | 1 |

I am able to run this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(w, '-', l) FROM (SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(Result) FROM GameSummaries WHERE Result = 'W') AS w,
    (SELECT COUNT(Result) FROM GameSummaries WHERE Result = 'L') AS l) as c
```

Which returns:
18-19

But I haven't been able to figure out the syntax to put them together.

My best effort is:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date), CONCAT(w, '-', l) FROM (SELECT
    (SELECT YEAR(Date), COUNT(Result) FROM GameSummaries WHERE Result = 'W' GROUP BY YEAR(Date)) AS w,
    (SELECT YEAR(Date), COUNT(Result) FROM GameSummaries WHERE Result = 'L' GROUP BY YEAR(Date)) AS l) as c
```

Which returns:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Only one expression can be
> specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
> EXISTS. Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Only one expression can be
> specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
> EXISTS. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Invalid column name
> 'Date'.

This seems like it should be fairly basic, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUM with a case statement as a trick

```
SELECT YEAR(date) as [year],
   sum(CASE WHEN Result = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + '-'
   sum(CASE WHEN Result = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [W-L]
FROM GameSummaries
GROUP BY Year(Date)
```

Note you may need to cast to string if you get an error change to this

```
   cast(sum(CASE WHEN Result = 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as varchar(20)) + '-'
   cast(sum(CASE WHEN Result = 'L' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as varchar(20)) as [W-L]
```